# Экранирование слэшей

Tags: c#, строки, экранирование

как стоит изменить код, чтобы он мог понимать, где идёт более 2 слэшей подряд?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
private static void ParseComplexField(string line, StringBuilder tokenBuilder, ref int nextSymbol, char typeOfQuotes)
    {
        for (; nextSymbol < line.Length; nextSymbol++)
        {
            if (line[nextSymbol] == '\\')
            {
                if (line[nextSymbol - 1] == '\\')
                    tokenBuilder.Append('\\');
            }
            else if (line[nextSymbol] == typeOfQuotes)
            {
                if (line[nextSymbol - 1] == '\\' && line[nextSymbol - 2] != '\\')
                    tokenBuilder.Append(typeOfQuotes);
                else
                    break;
            }
            else
                tokenBuilder.Append(line[nextSymbol]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: А зачем вам это понимать? Это очень смахивает на учебное задание, в котором достаточно было рассматривать два подряд идущих символа, не более того

Comment: Тут, видимо, в проблема в том, что у вас алгоритм неправильно работает, рассматривая третий слэш вместе со вторым, хотя второй уже "использован" вместе с первым

Comment: Нет, ну смотрите: "почему ответ получается неправильный?" и "как понимать наличие 3 слэшей подряд?" - это несколько разные вопросы, потому что первый в качестве ответа может подразумевать полное изменение алгоритма решения. А каковы полные условия задачи?

Comment: @Regent vk.cc/8BetQT и vk.cc/8Bet9u. Если завести счётчик, считывающий количество слэшей, то задача решается, однако цитирую "Ваш код пытается меня убедить в том, что важно, сколько символов слэш идёт подряд. На самом деле это не так. Важно лишь, был ли слэш предыдущим символом. Попытыйтесь избавиться от подсчета"

Comment: Всецело согласен с _"Важно лишь, был ли слэш предыдущим символом"_ :) Примерно то же самое я написал в первом комментарии, имея в виду как раз эту задачу. Не так давно доказывал человек, что не нужно тут знать, было ли 3 слэша подряда или нет

Comment: Учитывая что ваш вопрос по конкретной проблеме, а не по задаче в целом, я тогда предложу в ответе код, написанной на основе вашей логики (то есть неизвестно, корректен ли он для задачи в общем), но демонстрирующий вариант без счетчика

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обработки экранирования вместо заглядывания назад (по которому сложно что-то определить наверняка) можно запоминать факт того, что следующий символ должен быть экранирован (то есть что следующий символ нужно сразу добавить в результат).

Решается это с помощью флага, значение которого устанавливается в true при нахождении символа экранирования (слэша):

```
private static void ParseComplexField(string line, StringBuilder tokenBuilder, ref int nextSymbol, char typeOfQuotes)
{
    var handleCharAsIs = false;
    for (; nextSymbol < line.Length; nextSymbol++)
    {
        if (handleCharAsIs)
        {
            tokenBuilder.Append(line[nextSymbol]);
            handleCharAsIs = false;
        }
        else if (line[nextSymbol] == '\\')
        {
            handleCharAsIs = true;
        }
        else if (line[nextSymbol] == typeOfQuotes)
        {
            //не знаю зачем это - видимо, для общей задачи
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            tokenBuilder.Append(line[nextSymbol]);
        }
    }
}
```

Результаты:

```
\\\\\\\\  ->  \\\\
abc       ->  abc
\\\abc\\  ->  \abc\
```

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ и объяснение! Все тесты проходят.